# Pygame Score per Click

Tags: pygame, click, scoreloop

I would like to create a program that whenever I pressed a mouse button, its score will be incrementing by 1.

here is my code so far:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))

def count():

    exit = True

while exit:

    mouseClick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            global score
            score = 0
            if mouseClick[0] == 1:
                score1=score+1
                print (score1)
            else:
                print (score)

    display.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
count()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way you handle `score`:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    global score
    score = 0
    if mouseClick[0] == 1:
        score1=score+1
        print (score1)
    else:
        print (score)
```

At every iteration, if a click is detected, you reset `score`.
So it's just always equal to `0`.

Just get rid of that `score = 0` (and of that `global score` as well), and put it right before your main loop:

```
score = 0
while exit:
    ...
```

Now, when you want to increment `score`, you don't need a second variable.
Instead, just write:

```
score += 1
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
score = score + 1
```

On the other hand, your code always redefines a new variable `score1`, and assign it to `score + 1`, which is equal to `1`.
So what you just have is a `score` variable always equal to `0`, and a `score1` variable always equal to `1`.

A logical way to handle all of this would be:

```
score = 0
while exit:    
    ...
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if mouseClick[0] == 1:
                score += 1
```

Comment: There is no output when if have:

if mouseClick[0] == 1:

So, I tried to removed it and if produces some the exact output..

Comment: I am having a quiz game, and it has 3 buttons, I would like have this score if have pressed the correct button. The thing is I don't know how to implement it inside the button function.. can you help me out?

Comment: @MarkAnthonyDeang Unfortunately, not in a comment. You should make an attempt by yourself, and if you happen not to manage to do it, post a new question. If you do so, you can send me a comment here so I'm notified.

Comment: @MarkAnthonyDeang What do you expect me to do with that? Please post a new question.

Comment: okay sir, I have tried attempting it but it seems it doesn't work though.. I will post a link for it sir. thank you